# gradle > Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED android_gradle_build.json (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, gradlew

I am trying to build an android project from the command line using

```
./gradlew app:assembleDebug
```

However when I build the task fails with:

```
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/hcwiley/MyProject/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/android_gradle_build.json (No such file or directory)
```

If I run `Sync Project with Gradle Files` in Android Studio it fixes the problem.

How do I do this from the command line so I don't have to launch Android Studio just for this basic thing?

Also to note, in newer versions of Gradle `.externalNativeBuild` has been replaced `.cxx`

I've already tried these to no avail:

```
rm -rf app/.externalNativeBuild app/build
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
./gradlew clean
```

My `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
#Mon Oct 07 16:53:24 CDT 2019
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try rerunning all tasks using `--rerun-tasks` command line parameter. This will force Gradle to run all tasks while ignoring up-to-date checks.
From [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html):

> This will force `test` [...or in your case, `app`] and all task dependencies of `test` to execute.
>   It’s a little like running `gradle clean test`, but without the build’s
>   generated output being deleted.

Comment: `./gradlew app:assembleDebug --rerun-tasks`

it worked !!! thank you

Comment: You should file bugs whenever you have to do that, FWIW. Any time you have to manually `--rerun-tasks` is a bug in the dependency tracking.

Comment: further note for future individuals. this also fixes issues with:

`error: package R does not exist`

Comment: you deserve a medal!! really!