# How can I regenerate android_gradle_build.json to make my NDK project build from Gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I have an NDK project that compiles under Android Studio, but not from the command-line in Gradle. In particular, it's missing /home/tim/git/jniApp/app/.cxx/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/android_gradle_build.json

I can't check in .cxx because it's stuffed full of absolute paths on my hard drive - useless for CI.

To reproduce a minimal example:

1. Create a new C++ project in Android Studio,
2. Build it with an ARM phone attached,
3. Delete the app/.cxx directory
4. Run ./gradlew clean
5. Build -> Refresh linked C++ projects
6. Run ./gradlew build

and that build fails because the aforementioned file is absent.

In particular, I'm left with this output:

```
$ ./gradlew build

> Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug
Build native-lib_armeabi-v7a
ninja: Entering directory `/home/tim/git/jniApp/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a'
ninja: no work to do.
Build native-lib_arm64-v8a
ninja: Entering directory `/home/tim/git/jniApp/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a'
ninja: no work to do.
Build native-lib_x86
ninja: Entering directory `/home/tim/git/jniApp/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86'
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/tim/git/jniApp/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libnative-lib.so
Build native-lib_x86_64
ninja: Entering directory `/home/tim/git/jniApp/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86_64'
ninja: no work to do.

> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildRelease'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/tim/git/jniApp/app/.cxx/cmake/release/armeabi-v7a/android_gradle_build.json (No such file or directory)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
38 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 32 up-to-date
```

It doesn't seem to matter whether I opt for CMake or ndk-build (I'd prefer ndk-build, but I'll take CMake if I can get a command-line build that doesn't care about the host absolute paths).

Is there a Gradle target to generate that missing file - or better the whole .cxx directory?

Seems this is an Android Studio bug, if there isn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293793/gradle-task-appexternalnativebuilddebug-failed-android-gradle-build-json-no

Comment: @vyshnav - thanks, I'll give it a go.